# How do I include an attribute in the OpenRefine export template?

Tags: templates, attributes, export, openrefine

I am trying to write a Dublin Core Export template in Open refine that also includes attributes

```
{{forNonBlank(cells["CREATOR"], v, "<dc:creator xsi:type="dcterms:URI">"+v.value+"</dc:creator>", "")}}
```

but it seems it doesn't like my " in xsi:type="dcterms:URI"

so i tried to espace this with " but it also didnt work

```
{{forNonBlank(cells["CREATOR"], v, "<dc:creator xsi:type=&quot;dcterms:URI&quot;>"+v.value+"</dc:creator>", "")}}
```

I expect:

```
<dc:creator xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://d-nb.info/gnd/1143725255</dc:creator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the quotes with a `\`:

```
{{forNonBlank(cells["CREATOR"], v, "<dc:creator xsi:type=\"dcterms:URI\">"+v.value+"</dc:creator>", "")}}
```

or you can use single quotes in the GREL and double quotes in the text (or the other way around)

```
{{forNonBlank(cells["CREATOR"], v, '<dc:creator xsi:type="dcterms:URI">'+v.value+'</dc:creator>', "")}}
```